# A circle intersection problem

Tags: geometry

The circles k1 and k2 intersect at points A and B. One of the common tangents at them touches each circle at points M and N respectively. Calculate the sum of the convex angles ∠ MAN and ∠ MBN.

Comment: Where did you stuck?

Comment: Well, I tried putting that part with the angles in another circle, but I'm not sure if that's correct. That also in some cases couldn't help to find the answer, since, for that, M, N, and A/B would need to be on a single circle, which isn't the case for every example. I didn't get any ideas after that.

Comment: ""The" common tangent". But there are two of them. You surely mean : "consider one of the two common tangents..."

Comment: Edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of the angles is equal to $\pi$

Pf: Since $(MBA)$ is inscript over the segment $AM$, then it is congruent with the angle $(AMN)$ being $MN$ a tangent line. The same argument yields that $(ABN)$ and $(ANM)$ are congruent. Then, since (as angles) $MBN+MAN=MBA+ABN+A=AMN+MNA+NAM=\pi$.
 $\Box$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Note that due to the shared arc AM and AN, we have ∠NMA = ∠MBA and ∠MNA = ∠NBA, respectively. Then,
$$\angle MAN = 180 - ( \angle NMA + \angle MNA ) 
= 180 - ( \angle MBA + \angle NBA) = 180 - \angle MBN$$

Thus, ∠MAN + ∠MBN = 180$^\circ$.

Comment: Thank you very much!